# Intel compiler inline size

Tags: c++, gcc, inline, icc

I have been compiling my code for some time with `g++` and then moved to Intel's `icpc` compiler. With `icpc` I kept getting the following warnings:

```
remark #11074: Inlining inhibited by limit max-size 
remark #11074: Inlining inhibited by limit max-total-size
```

I never had this problem with `g++`. After some research, I understood that I can compile with `-no-inline-max-total-size` and `-no-inline-total-size` to avoid limits on inlining size. My question is whether it is always a good practice to remove sizes on inlining and inline as much as possible? My code is computation heavy and performance is key, therefore my common sense dictates that I should allow as much inlining as possible for the compiler. Is that true? Are there situations at all where imposing an inlining limit is useful?

Comment: Inlining is not always a net gain, it can have a negative impact on performance. See [this article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-and-perf). You should not tell the compiler what to inline. Trust that it is better than you at making the decision of what to inline. Unless you have proven, with tools and measurements, that forcing inline is beneficial, you shouldn't. The compiler can inline whatever it wants via the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: thanks! So does that mean that the g++ compiler also had some inlining limit, it just didn't issue any warning about it?

Comment: @Botond: Yes, exactly.  You can adjust this limit in g++ with the [`-finline-limit` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).  There is also the `-Winline` option if you want to be informed when a function declared `inline` does not get inlined.

Comment: I'm not well informed regarding specific compiler implementation details. It is possible. Maybe if you shared a [MCVE] it would be possible to compare the assembly that the compilers output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether it is always a good practice to remove sizes on inlining and inline as much as possible?

No, it is not always a good pratice to remove size limits on inlining nor to inline as much as possible.

Ideally, inlining should be done only when it improves performance.

> Are there situations at all where imposing an inlining limit is useful?

If a function is very large, and it is called from many contexts, then inlining such function to all of those contexts will bloat the executable. If the executable itself is let's say several gigabytes because of inlining, then loading the program from the disk may become the bottleneck.

In less pathological cases, the trade-offs are more subtle. The way to find out optimal limits is measurement. Profile guided optimisation can give the optimiser more useful heuristics than simple hard limits.